# Azure AppService - How to connect and deploy front and back

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I'm absolutely new to Azure, CI, and CD.
I have an app consisting of a frontend developed under React + Typescript which sends CRUD requests to a typescript backend. Both front and end are NPM projects.

I've no idea on how to step from development environment to production, deploying to Azure.
Should I create two separate AppServices, one for each project?

If that's the case, how do I then connect them?
Do I just need to change the URL the server listens to?

As you can see I've no idea of what I'm doing but I'm eager to learn so any feedback is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach is

1. Deploy frontend app ( react ) in one app service.
2. Backend nodejs app on a different app service.
3. Then, call the api of the nodejs app from the frontend.

Or,

Set up and run the client and server on the same server using a gulp file and deploy that project on an app service. In that case, there is no cross-site communication. This is the most preferred one.

1. Using the same app service for both front end and back end application. Refer [nodeexpress-backend-with-angular-front-end-in-a-single-azure-web-app](https://pretagteam.com/question/nodeexpress-backend-with-angular-front-end-in-a-single-azure-web-app).
   Using Cors to connect front end and backend [Check here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-react-frontend-a-node-express-backend-and-connect-them-together-c5798926047c/)

Refer SO [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64667861/15997690) & [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39682469/15997690)

And You can use  [deploy staging slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) in app service to use different environment like (test/dev, Production).

Comment: thanks, will read up on it!